# How do i place word restriction on html and php

Tags: php, html

i was trying to do a word restriction for a text field post linking to twitter, however twitter have the character limit of 140 words thus unable to post it online. Does anyone knows how to program a coding for both html and php to fix this problem.

Comment: -1 Did you tried something?

Comment: Twitter has a character limit of 140, not a word limit of 140

Answer (score 2):

Simple examle:

```
 $input = $_POST['field'];

    if(strlen($input)> 140)
    {
    // Error or substr()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
function LimitCharacter($data,$limit = 20)
{
    if (strlen($data) > $limit)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```